# String doesn't change based on language - Custom translation hook

Tags: react-native, react-hooks, react-redux

In the app I'm currently working on I have a custom hook useTranslation.
The hook is meant to take the correct labels based on a language stored in store and a key given to it.

In most cases this hook works perfectly so the problem probably isn't here.

I have only encountered the problem in a few variables. For example in my SettingsScreen I have 2 variables that will not change no matter what language is selected.

The variables are:

1. InitialInactivityOption:

```
const inactiveOptions = [
    { text: `0 ${t("minutes")}`, value: 0 },
    { text: `5 ${t("minutes")}`, value: 5 },
    { text: `10 ${t("minutes")}`, value: 10 },
    { text: `15 ${t("minutes")}`, value: 15 },
  ];

  const initialInactivityOption = inactiveOptions.find(
    (option) => option.value === inactivityTimer
  ).text;
```

2. InitialValue (1st MultiSelectSetting)

```
initialValue={
    authMode === "credentials" ? t("noAuth") : t("biometrics")
}
```

I'm assuming the problem lies with how I made these variables, I have tried both:

- using UseMemo with language dependency
- changing them to be useStates and changing the values in useEffect with lanuage dependency

Full code below

useTranslation:

```
import { useSelector } from "react-redux";

export default function useTranslation() {
  const language = useSelector((state) => state.SettingsReducer.language);

  let labels = "";
  switch (language) {
    case "nl":
      labels = require("../services/languages/nl.json");
      break;
    case "fr":
      labels = require("../services/languages/fr.json");
      break;

    default:
      labels = require("../services/languages/eng.json");
      break;
  }

  const searchValue = (key) => {
    return labels[key];
  };

  return searchValue;
}
```

SettingsScreen:

```
import { View, Text, TouchableOpacity, StyleSheet } from "react-native";
import React from "react";
import useTranslation from "../hooks/useTranslation";
import { useDispatch, useSelector } from "react-redux";
import {
  selectAuth,
  selectLanguage,
  updateInactivityTimer,
} from "../store/settings/settings";
import { FlatList } from "react-native-gesture-handler";
import styleSheet, { Colors, defaultShadow } from "../services/StyleSheet";
import useBiometricAuth from "../hooks/useBiometricAuth";
import { Image } from "@rneui/themed";
import { useState } from "react";
import { useEffect } from "react";
import {
  getRememberMeValues,
  saveToSecureStorage,
} from "../services/SecureStorageFunctions";
import SignOutButton from "../components/SignOutButton";
import CreditsAndVersionDisplay from "../components/creditsAndVersionDisplay";
import MultiSelectSetting from "../components/MultiSelectSetting";

const SettingsScreen = () => {
  const t = useTranslation();
  const dispatch = useDispatch();

  const authMode = useSelector((state) => state.SettingsReducer.authMode);
  const language = useSelector((state) => state.SettingsReducer.language);
  const inactivityTimer = useSelector(
    (state) => state.SettingsReducer.inactivityTimer
  );

  const { hasBiometricAuth } = useBiometricAuth();

  const [credentialsSaved, setCredentialsSaved] = useState(false);

  useEffect(() => {
    getRememberMeValues().then((result) => setCredentialsSaved(!!result));
  }, []);

  const languageArray = [
    {
      name: "Nederlands",
      value: "nl",
      onPress: () => {
        saveToSecureStorage("language", "nl");
        dispatch(selectLanguage("nl"));
      },
      uri: "" //DATASTRING REMOVED TO REMAIN READABLE,
    },
    {
      name: "Français",
      value: "fr",
      onPress: () => {
        saveToSecureStorage("language", "fr");
        dispatch(selectLanguage("fr"));
      },
      uri: "" //DATASTRING REMOVED TO REMAIN READABLE,
    },
    {
      name: "English",
      value: "eng",
      onPress: () => {
        saveToSecureStorage("language", "eng");
        dispatch(selectLanguage("eng"));
      },
      uri:"" //DATASTRING REMOVED TO REMAIN READABLE,
    },
  ];

  const authOptions = [
    {
      text: t("noAuth"),
      value: "credentials",
      icon: "lock-open",
      disabled: !credentialsSaved,
    },
    {
      text: t("biometrics"),
      value: "biometrics",
      icon: "fingerprint",
      disabled: !hasBiometricAuth && !credentialsSaved,
    },
  ];

  const inactiveOptions = [
    { text: `0 ${t("minutes")}`, value: 0 },
    { text: `5 ${t("minutes")}`, value: 5 },
    { text: `10 ${t("minutes")}`, value: 10 },
    { text: `15 ${t("minutes")}`, value: 15 },
  ];

  const initialInactivityOption = inactiveOptions.find(
    (option) => option.value === inactivityTimer
  ).text;

  return (
    <View
      style={[
        styleSheet.container,
        { backgroundColor: "light gray", padding: 8 },
      ]}
    >
      <View style={[styles.settings_block, { marginVertical: "10%" }]}>
        <Text style={styles.settings_block_title}>{t("security")}</Text>

        <MultiSelectSetting
          title={t("authMode")}
          description={t("authModeDescription")}
          initialValue={
            authMode === "credentials" ? t("noAuth") : t("biometrics")
          }
          options={authOptions}
          onChange={(value) => {
            dispatch(selectAuth(value));
          }}
        />

        <MultiSelectSetting
          title={t("inactivityTimer")}
          description={t("inactivityTimerDescription")}
          initialValue={initialInactivityOption}
          height={280}
          options={inactiveOptions}
          onChange={(value) => {
            dispatch(updateInactivityTimer(value));
          }}
        />

        <SignOutButton />
      </View>

      <CreditsAndVersionDisplay />
    </View>
  );
};

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  settings_block: {
    ...defaultShadow,
    paddingVertical: 15,
    backgroundColor: "white",
    borderRadius: 10,
    paddingHorizontal: 15,
    marginTop: 10,
  },
  settings_block_title: {
    fontSize: 18,
    marginBottom: 15,
    fontWeight: "bold",
    color: Colors.base_text,
  },
});

export default SettingsScreen;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A colleague was able to help me with this. The mistake I made was in the MultiSelectSetting component. I passed the initialValue as initialState for useState, this ensured that my "translation" remained at the 1st language. I replaced the .text for the inactivityTimer with .value and gave authMode for the authenticationMethod and made another .find() in MultiSelectSetting to get the text I need to show.

```
{options.find((option) => option.value === value).text}
```

full component code below

```
import { useState } from "react";
import { Text, FlatList, View, TouchableOpacity } from "react-native";
import { Colors } from "../services/StyleSheet";
import { Overlay } from "@rneui/themed";
import { FontAwesome5 } from "@expo/vector-icons";

const MultiSelectSetting = ({
  title,
  description,
  initialValue,
  height,
  options,
  onChange,
}) => {
  const [selectVisible, setSelectVisible] = useState(false);
  const [value, setValue] = useState(initialValue);

  return (
    <>
      <TouchableOpacity
        onPress={() => setSelectVisible(true)}
        style={{ marginBottom: 15 }}
      >
        <View
          style={{
            flexDirection: "row",
            justifyContent: "space-between",
            alignItems: "center",
          }}
        >
          <View style={{ width: "60%" }}>
            <Text style={{ color: Colors.base_text, marginBottom: 5 }}>
              {title}
            </Text>
            <Text
              style={{
                color: Colors.base_text,
                opacity: 0.6,
                fontSize: 12,
              }}
            >
              {description}
            </Text>
          </View>
          <Text
            style={{
              color: Colors.primary_darker,
              fontWeight: "bold",
              opacity: 0.75,
            }}
          >
            {options.find((option) => option.value === value).text}
          </Text>
        </View>
      </TouchableOpacity>
      <Overlay
        isVisible={selectVisible}
        overlayStyle={{
          paddingHorizontal: 20,
          paddingVertical: 15,
          borderRadius: 5,
          width: "80%",
          height: height ?? 230,
        }}
        onBackdropPress={() => setSelectVisible(false)}
      >
        <Text style={{ fontSize: 21, marginBottom: 10 }}>{title}</Text>
        <FlatList
          data={options}
          renderItem={({ item }) => (
            <TouchableOpacity
              disabled={item.disabled}
              style={{
                paddingVertical: 5,
                marginVertical: 10,
                paddingHorizontal: 8,
              }}
              onPress={() => {
                setValue(item.text);
                onChange(item.value);
                setSelectVisible(false);
              }}
            >
              {item.icon ? (
                <View
                  style={{
                    flexDirection: "row",
                    ...(item.disabled && { opacity: 0.3 }),
                  }}
                >
                  <FontAwesome5
                    name={item.icon}
                    size={20}
                    color={Colors.primary_darker}
                    style={{ marginRight: 8, width: 25 }}
                  />
                  <Text>{item.text}</Text>
                </View>
              ) : (
                <Text>{item.text}</Text>
              )}
            </TouchableOpacity>
          )}
          keyExtractor={(_, index) => index.toString()}
        />
      </Overlay>
    </>
  );
};

export default MultiSelectSetting;
```